# Business Logic Layer in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, architecture

I'm struggling to find some information about where I should put my Business logic. I have an N-Tier Win Forms application that I want to move into a ASP.NET MVC 4 application.

Can I reuse the existing BLL and DAL objects? If so, do I connect them to the models or the controllers?

Comment: What is the structure of you existing windows application? Do you have Entity or Domain projects in you structure?

Comment: could you provide some high level information about your current application?

Comment: Yes, UI is winforms connecting to the BLL (separate class library) that in turn uses the DAL (separate class library) to read and write to a SQL server backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as an example:
you have a BLL class

```
public class StudentDLL: IStudentDLL
{

 public List<student> GetAll()
  {
   //you can add your BLL here or the DLL be referenced in your BLL
    return List<student>(){ new student()
    {
      studentid=1,studentname="David"
       },
     new student(){
     studentid=2,studentname="Andrew"
     },new student(){
     studentid=3,studentname="Mark"
     }}
  }}
```

and on your controller you will have

```
 public class StudentController: Controller
  {
   public IStudentDLL _student;

  public StudentController(IStudentDLL student){
  _student = student;
  }
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
     var studentList= _student.GetAll();
    var model= studentList;

    return View Index("Index", model);
    }
   }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

your controller will be accessing your top Layer(either BLL or DAL depending on your topology). As long as your BLL/DAL have interfaces and this will be a good way to refactor and test your classes

Comment: OK, but how? I'm struggling to find any examples of how this is done.

Comment: Look at the example below or go to http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/871375/Understanding-ASP-NET-MVC-using-real-world-example